# How to accept or reject the data using checkbox in codeiginter?

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I am accepting and rejecting some data while clicking checkbox.From my code accept code is working well but rejected is same type of code but it is not working well.

My view page code:

```
 <form  class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?=site_url('Request/Update_Event')?>">
    <div class="panel panel-flat" id="id">
      <div  class="panel-heading">
       <center> <h4 class="panel-title">Request Portal</h4></center>

      </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>Approved
        </button> <a href="<?=site_url('Request/Rejected')?>" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="but">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> Rejected
        </a><div>
```

My Controller Code:

```
public function Update_Event(){
    $empid = $this->input->post('empid');
        for($i=0; $i< sizeof($empid); $i++)
    {

        $data = array(
            'backgroundColor' => 'green',
            'event_status' =>'Approved',
        );
        $this->db->where(empid,$empid[$i]);
        $this->db->update('events',$data);
}

redirect('Request','refresh');
}
public function Rejected(){
$empid = $this->input->post('empid');
        for($i=0; $i< sizeof($empid); $i++)
    {

        $data = array(
            'backgroundColor' => 'red',
            'event_status' =>'Rejected',
        );
        $this->db->where(empid,$empid[$i]);
        $this->db->update('events',$data);
}

redirect('Request','refresh');
print_r($empid);
}
```

My table code:

```
<table id="tb2" class="table datatable-responsive" >
    <thead><tr><h6><th></th><th  align="center">Name</th>
            <th class="col-sm" >Leave Date</th>
            <th class="col-sm" >Reason</th>
    </tr></thead>
            <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>                          
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="empid[]" value="<?php echo $row['empid'];?>"></td>
    <td>Leave Applied By <?php echo $row['first_name'];?> <?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['event_date']));?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['title'];?> </td>

</tr></tbody><?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
```

The rejected code is not working in my code and the empid is not passed to Rejected code when i print the empid value

Comment: check what actually you getting post values in controller echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);exit;

Comment: empty array Array
(
)

Comment: so there is nothing posted then check the data you are passing into check box values  present or not !

Comment: i have checked for approved button the value is passed correctly but in rejected code it is not passing the value correctly

Answer (score 2):

You are facing this issue because at approval time you are submitting form and in rejection time you are only clicking on link. So when you click on reject button it will not post any value to controller.

You can do something like this. just pass extra parameter to reject function.

```
<a href="<?=site_url('Request/Rejected/123')?>" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="but">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> Rejected
</a>


public function Rejected($empid = ''){
        for($i=0; $i< sizeof($empid); $i++)
    {

        $data = array(
            'backgroundColor' => 'red',
            'event_status' =>'Rejected',
        );
        $this->db->where(empid,$empid[$i]);
        $this->db->update('events',$data);
}

redirect('Request','refresh');
print_r($empid);
}
```